# how do mining pools expose their stats?

Tags: mining-pools, api

Webistes like https://miningpoolstats.stream/ must communicate with the pools somehow. What protocol do they use to retrieve information such as the pool's hashrate and what blocks have been mined by that pool? If I make my own pool what is the necessary API to expose this information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we know which miner or pool mined a block?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/75115/how-do-we-know-which-miner-or-pool-mined-a-block)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. This question asks how they get API data from pools, not which miner or pool solved a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mining pools export this functionality via API's.

For example, poolin's API docs are here: https://btc.com/api-doc

Here's F2Pool's : https://www.f2pool.com/developer/api

And so forth.

The way aggregators add value is by compiling all this data from different pools into a neat user interface.